# How to retrieve row from Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

How to retrieve row from sqlite3 from table when I have rowid meta data(sqlite global   val)from sqlite3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The ROWID in SQLite is an alias for the "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY".

```
       select * from myTable where foo = {the rowid value in question}

       (where foo is the name you have given to the integer primary key column in the CREATE TABLE statement)
```